# KAFKA Stream OOM (Out of Memory)

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams

My KAFKA Stream java application goes to ERROR status due to an out of memory problem.
I use windowed aggregation, mainly in order to calculate median values:

- a 1 second windows
  `.windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).advanceBy(Duration.ofMillis(999)).grace(Duration.ofMillis(1)))` with `.suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded().withMaxBytes(10000).withLoggingDisabled()))`
- 30 seconds windows without suppress `.windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(30)).advanceBy(Duration.ofSeconds(2)).grace(Duration.ofMillis(1)))`

I have also a steate store:`

```
    StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, Gateway>> kvStoreBuilder = Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(
            Stores.persistentKeyValueStore(AppConfigs.GW_STATE_STORE_NAME),
            Serdes.String(),
            JsonSerdes.getGatewaySerde()
    );
    // add state store to StreamBuilder
    builder.addStateStore(kvStoreBuilder);`
```

Eclipse memory analyzer says that:

One instance of ‘org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.InMemoryTimeOrderedKeyValueBuffer’ loaded by ‘jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader @ 0xf00d8558’ occupies 238,753,712 (90.51%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of ‘java.util.HashMap$Node[]’, loaded by ‘’, which occupies 238,749,768 (90.51%) bytes.

[image: With visual VM it seems that]

Can anyone explain which should be the root cause ?

Answer (score 4):

The error is from `suppress()` that use the in-memory store (`InMemoryTimeOrderedKeyValueBuffer`). `suppress()` does not support RocksDB atm (cf https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7224).

Your `suppress()` config seems to be incorrect:

```
Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded().withMaxBytes(10000).withLoggingDisabled()
```

The configs `unbounded()` and `withMaxBytes()` contradict each other: do you want an unbounded or bounded buffer? -- In your case, the second `withMaxBytes()` overwrites the first one. Thus, you only provide `10,000` bytes for the suppress buffer. Because you use `untilWindowCloses()`, Kafka Streams will need to shut down if it runs out of memory, because it's neither allows to early emit (`untilWindowClose()`) not allowed to use more memory (`withMaxBytes(...)`).

For `untilWindowClose()` you should use `unbounded()`. If you want to bound memory, you should not use `untilWindowClose()`.

Comment: tyvm for the answer.
When you say that I should not use untilWindowClose(), the alternative is untilTimeLimit() and in this way I can use a EagerBufferConfig. But can I obtain the same effect? I want to aggregate messages in the same second (i use also a TimestampExtractor), so, with the following code, for example, can I do that ?
.suppress(Suppressed.untilTimeLimit(Duration.ofSeconds(1) ,Suppressed.BufferConfig.maxBytes(10000)))

Comment: another question: If I enabled logging (.withLoggingEnabled()), the suppressed outputs are saved in a changelog kafka topic. In this way a don't use my internal memory, right? Can I also set a valid retention policy on this changelog toipc? I tried to do that, but It seems ignored.

Comment: Using `untilWindowClose()` and `untilTimeLimit()` is not the exact same thing: `untilWindowClose()` guarantees that there will be a single result record (if buffer space is sufficient -- otherwise, your app shuts down). In contrast, using `untilTimeLimit()` you don't get a strict guarantee that you get only a single result -- if you run out of buffer space, the current (intermediate) result will be flushed downstream (and your app won't shut down).

Comment: For the changelog, it's only for fault-tolerance (it highly recommended to keep it enabled -- otherwise you loose the buffered data during rebalance). It has no impact on used memory, as during regular processing we only write into it; the topic is only read in case of state/buffer recovery. -- The topic also does not use retention time, but it's a compacted topic and the `suppress()` operator will write so-called tombstone records to delete data. Thus, you don't need to worry about managing the changelog topic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tune the rocks DB configuration, please read this https://medium.com/@grinfeld_433/kafka-streams-and-rocksdb-in-the-space-time-continuum-and-a-little-bit-of-configuration-40edb5ee9ed7

If you are using java>=8, set metaspace otherwise it will eat all your server RAM. http://karunsubramanian.com/websphere/one-important-change-in-memory-management-in-java-8/

If using dockers, limit the max memory configs.

There is a bug in old kafka and they recommend to update version.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8637